# What is the reason for the confluent Bigquery connector v2.5 not assigning partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I get the following error with the Bigquery sink connector v2.5 from confluent:

> WARN [debezium-connector-bigquery|task-0]
> WorkerSinkTask{id=debezium-connector-bigquery-0} Ignoring invalid task
> provided offset  -- partition not assigned

I have 8 default partitions for each topic in kafka. I set `tasks.max` to 10 in the Bigquery connector config. Should the partitions match the tasks.max?

I would assume that the `tasks.max` is applicable for all the topics. Should I increase the tasks.max value to more than 10? I know 10 is the default. I currently have about 12 topics.

I changed the `tasks.max` value to 24 (multiple of 8) and to 8 and the error did not go away. I was hoping that this will resolve the problem.